# Local helm repo not updated from Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

Setting ACR for hosting helm chart but getting some strange behavior.

Facts:

- ACR added as repo locally, authenticated etc.
- Tried adding the helm repo both with the *helm repo add* and *az acr helm repo add* command
- Using ACR admin user for authentication.
- Using Windows
- Tried helm v3.10.1 and v3.10.2

Scenario #1:

- pushing a helm chart with *az acr helm push --name someacr .\someapi1-0.1.3.tgz*
- I can see the chart in the portal
- Issuing *helm repo update --debug* (no errors)
- When issuing *helm search repo -l*, there's nothing
- Trying *helm pull*, also results in no chart

Scenario #2

- pushing helm chart with *az acr helm push --name someacr .\someapi1-0.1.3.tgz*
- I do **not** see the chart in the portal
- Issuing *helm repo update --debug* (no errors)
- When issuing *helm search repo -l*, I **do** see the chart
- Trying helm pull, also results in downloading the chart

2 questions:

1. Can anyone explain when pushing with helm, I cannot see or pull the charts in the local repo? Essentially not use acr with native helm
2. When using the *az acr helm wrapper*, why can I not see the charts in the portal? Updating the local helm repo works and I can pull the charts down as expected - why?

I've seen a similar post, but no solution.
[Helm 3 search shows no result from ACR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553094/helm-3-search-shows-no-result-from-acr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using helm (and not az acr which is deprecated), you need to specify OCI by specifying the full OCI url. Note OCI is enabled by default from v3.8+
E.g.

```
helm push .\someapi1-0.1.4.tgz oci://someacr.azurecr.io/helm
helm pull oci://someacr.azurecr.io/helm/someapi1 --version 0.1.4
```

I can now push to the registry, see the charts in the Azure portal and pull them down again. One caveat with OCI seems to be that the local repo is not updated and you cannot use helm search either.